# How to Update Existing Disconnected Entity

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have this code which works in EntityFrameworkCore.

```
public void SaveProject(Project item)
    {
        var existing = _context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == item.Id);
        existing.Description = item.Description;
        existing.IsArchived = item.IsArchived;
        existing.IsDeleted = item.IsDeleted;
        existing.Name = item.Name;
        _context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

It taking a disconnected entity, finding it in the database, and applying the changes.

Is there a better way to do this?

I would like to not make a call to the database.  In other words, I would like to be able to mark the entity as modified, and then call SaveChanges().

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EntityFramework Core, it can now be done using the Update method:

```
 DbContext.Update<Item>(item);
 this.SaveChanges();
```

In version 2.1, the Update method can now be used for both new and existing entities if the Id property is auto-generated.

[The Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities)

The downside to this is that *all* properties are marked as modified, even if they are the same. The issue with this is that if you are logging changes in a database trigger, then every property will be flagged as changed, even when they are not. If you only want specific properties updated, then you need to get the entity from the database, update as desired, then save.

Answer (score 6):

If you are certain that item exist in database, you can use Attach method of DbContext As following

```
public void SaveProject(Project item)
{
    _context.Projects.Attach(item);
    _context.Entity(item).State=EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I think this will update ALL properties of the entity

Answer (score 1):

This will avoid making the unnessicary first trip to the database and only update the properties you specify.

```
foreach (Project item in data) {
    var existing = new _context.Project();
    existing.Id = item.Id; // Set the identity
    _context.Attach(existing); // Starts change tracking
    existing.Description = item.Description; // Any props updated after the .Attach() will be automatically tracked as changed.
    existing.IsArchived = item.IsArchived;
    existing.Name = item.Name;
    // etc...
    // Any properties NOT changed after .Attach() WILL NOT be included in the the generated UPDATE statement.
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This approach is not valid for generuc types

Answer (score 0):

I created the following extension methods to update only specific values (specified in `updateAction`) after finding the disconnected entity by its primary key.

Scenario: I have an ASP Core page that uses only parts of the Entity in its view and that are being transferred from/to the Web tier through DTOs that do not have all the fields

```
public static T FindByPrimaryKey<T>(this DbContext context, T disconnectedEntity) where T : class
{
    var keyValues = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties
        .Select(p => typeof(T).GetProperty(p.Name))
        .Select(p => p.GetValue(disconnectedEntity)).ToArray();

    var connectedEntity = context.Find<T>(keyValues);

    return connectedEntity;
}

public static void UpdateByPrimaryKey<T>(this DbContext context, T disconnectedEntity, Action<T> updateAction) where T : class
{
    var connectedEntity = context.FindByPrimaryKey(disconnectedEntity);

    updateAction(connectedEntity);
}
```