# What is the correct way of updating a record from the view model?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, entity-framework-core

Still working on my first UWP/MVVM/EF Core application.

I don't want my viewmodels to have any knowledge of the DbContext. So I created the following ItemService class, injected into my view models.

```cs
public class ItemService : IItemService
{
    public async Task SaveAsync(Item item)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            db.Items.Add(item);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

My ItemViewModel contains the following command :

```cs
public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

private async void Save()
{
    if (!SaveCommand.CanExecute(Item))
        return;

    await ItemService.SavAsync(Item);
}
```

This works great when I save an item. The SaveAsync method creates a new instance of the DbContext, adds the just created item and then commits the changes to the database.

My question is about the updating of an existing record. I thoug about something like this :

```cs
public class ItemService : IItemService
{
    public async Task UpdateAsync(Item item)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            Item dbItem = (from i in db.Items
                           where i.Id = item.Id
                           select i).FirstOrDefault();

            // Here I should duplicate all the item's properties into dbItem ones

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I just don't like this solution !
I have to copy all the properties of item into dbItem. What if I forgot one ? I could implement ICloneable but I find it a real overhead to do that for ALL my entities.

So what is the correct pattern here. The best way to update a record managed by a view model ?

Many thanks in advance,
Julien

Comment: I hardly see a 'better' way, after all that is what updating is. You could CHECK every properties to avoid rewriting those that didn't change, but still, you're gonna have to work on every properties at some point.

Comment: You can use Automapper http://automapper.org/ to avoid any mapping issues

Comment: Automapper is the last refuge of a scoundrel.  Don't use it.  And your real question is "how do I update a detached model in EF core?"  It doesn't really have anything to do with wpf and mvvm.

Comment: (note that Automapper is good for copying fields from one object instance to another, but reconnecting your instance to the context is a better choice. I would answer, but I don't know if EF Core is different in this respect than EF 6, which I do know)

Comment: @Will Automapper is the first refuge of busy people.

Comment: @MikeBrind I've seen people end up being busier when using it.  Particularly when they get the idiotic idea that they should make almost exact copies of every single model in their DAL in order to have "separation".

Comment: @Will, what do you mean by reconnecting the instance to the context. I have the feeling that this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416702/how-to-update-existing-disconnected-entity

Comment: IMHO, the answer to my question was given by @Will 's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Repository pattern on your app.Then you can completely decoupled your DAL layer from the ViewmModels.On the service layer where you can use AutoMapper to map ViewModel to Entity and verse versa.At this moment you can do it on your Service layer.But you have to introduce separate layer for the Repository pattern (i.e. DAL) with the Dependency injection.Then you don't need to worry about the mix of VMs and Entities.In other words those are on 2 separate layers if you implement above pattern.

Hence you're using EF core, you can use [**Autofac**](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) as a DI API.

What is AutoMapper?

> AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively
>   complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to
>   another. This type of code is rather dreary and boring to write, so
>   why not invent a tool to do it for us?

Here is the link : [**AutoMapper**](http://automapper.org/)

Good article : [**Generic Repository and Unit of Work Pattern, Entity Framework,Autofac**](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc)

As suggested  by **@Sean Stayn** where you can use [**Prism**](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism).see that too.

> Prism is a framework for building loosely coupled, maintainable, and
>   testable XAML applications in WPF, Windows 10 UWP, and Xamarin Forms.

Comment: If you use AutoFac and Dependency Injection, I recommend Prism 6 for UWP. It's very helpful to start with DI and UWP!

Comment: I don't agree with you.here it is from the OP `I have to copy all the properties of item into dbItem. What if I forgot one ?`.Then `Automapper` will do what he needs to do.B'cos if you configure `Automapper` correctly, then it'll never forget any property to map :D @Will

Comment: Aaah, I see where you're coming from on that.  However, all he has to do is re-attach the model and mark it as changed.  It's much simpler to do than importing a new dependency.  But that is one solution, yes.

Comment: hehe..Then you can `Up vote` insted of `Down vote` no ?  :D @Will

Comment: I didn't vote at all... I said "I want to downvote".  I withdraw my complaint and delete it, to make sure I'm not confusing any visitors.

Comment: Aha..OK sure.no problem. :D @Will

Comment: I have updated your suggestion too.please see that.Thanks :) @SeanStayn