# ASP .NET One-to-One Relationship CRUD

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

There's a problem with Edit action autogenerated with controller on the basis of a code-first class **UserProfile**.

```
public class UserProfile : ApplicationUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePhoto { get; set; }
        public string Interests { get; set; }
        public string AboutMe { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public List<Friends> Friends { get; set; }
        public List<Messages> Messages { get; set; }
        public List<UsersGallery> UsersGallery { get; set; }
    }
```

**UserProfile** is in one-to-one relationship with class **Address**.

```
public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public string AddressId { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string HouseOrFlatNumber { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string UserProfileForeignKey { get; set; }
        public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }
```

The relationship is described in FluentApi as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<UserProfile>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Address)
            .WithOne(i => i.UserProfile)
            .HasForeignKey<Address>(b => b.UserProfileForeignKey);
        }
```

The UserProfile and Address entities are created in **Register** action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new UserProfile { UserName = model.FirstName, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, Address = new Address() };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
                    await _emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(model.Email, callbackUrl);

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

At this point I have the appropriate entries in the database tables related by the UserProfileForeignKey.
- the UserProfile table
[the UserProfile table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBn7F.jpg)
- the Address table
[the Address table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpGQj.jpg)

And here appears a problem. According to the sql error message, the autogenerated CRUD action **Edit** instead of altering the entry in Address table tries to add a new entry with the same UserProfileForeignKey.

Do I understand it correctly? Why is that so and what can be done to make the Edit action work as it should?

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("FirstName,LastName,BirthDate,ProfilePhoto,Interests,AboutMe,Address,Id,UserName,NormalizedUserName,Email,NormalizedEmail,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,ConcurrencyStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEnd,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount")] UserProfile userProfile)
        {
            if (id != userProfile.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(userProfile);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!UserProfileExists(userProfile.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(userProfile);
        }
```

Here is the sql error message:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Address'
>   with unique index 'IX_Address_UserProfileForeignKey'.
>
> The duplicate key value is (9872561e-dad4-4169-9faf-154c7dcd925f). The statement has been terminated.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__108_0(Task
>   result) DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the
>   entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch+d__32.MoveNext()

It says the ForeignKey *9872561e-dad4-4169-9faf-154c7dcd925f* is tried to be duplicated but why if it is an update not an insert?

Comment: Set the entity state of the child (address) as shown by Aman or fetch it into tracking (you would then map changes back).

Comment: Thank you but could you suggest more details? How the attachement should look like and where should it be?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you UserProfile entity is detached (entity framework is not tracking it), so it sets entity.State == Added here.
To attach your entity please see [How to Update Existing Disconnected Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416702/how-to-update-existing-disconnected-entity)

**Edit 27/01/2018**
I tried to replicate your scenario and have created a project in GitHub https://github.com/updateaman/EF6-Test

After setting/passing the `UserProfileForeignKey` property inside `Address` object, I was able to get rid of this error

Comment: I tried like this:

`_context.Address.Attach(userProfile.Address);`
  ` _context.Entry(userProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;`
   `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`

and like this:

`_context.UserProfile.Attach(userProfile);
  _context.Entry(userProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;`
     `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`

still the same sql error about duplicating

Comment: I see that you are passing the Id for userProfile but not the addressId for Address, pass/set the addressId and try again

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. If you meant the binding, I already tried it along with the AddressId, but it doesn't work.
`public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("FirstName,LastName,BirthDate,ProfilePhoto,Interests,AboutMe,Address.AddressId,Address.City,Address.Street,Address.HouseOrFlatNumber,Address.PostalCode,Address.Country,Id,UserName,NormalizedUserName,Email,NormalizedEmail,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,ConcurrencyStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEnd,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount")] UserProfile userProfile)`

Comment: The error message changed however:___
 _DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions._

Comment: Good. Is any AddressId being in the request? do you see any value inside userProfile.Address.AddressId?

Comment: Here is the photo of the request [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lqOrgT9BruBxpSiz__zQkMUNiLZqCrx-)

Comment: It's not passing the addressId. Are you able to modify the request to pass addressId? alternatively you can just get it from database and set it on userProfile.Address.AddressId

Comment: I tried it in several ways but the Address field of userProfile is always null. Are the relations between UserProfile and Address in model classes right? I set them as in the tutorial  
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)  
under section: _Other Relationship Patterns - One to one_  .....  Or another question: How to include Address class in the Edit post method??

Comment: The relationship seems to be set up properly. Can you show what values are set inside userProfile object inside Edit method?

Comment: Here is the whole [Edit action](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zp5kCDHHEZoxxJf9aSj-Bl1FfiJgNwvm)  .... And here is the [content of userProfile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WusuvXMJCuvbsea_oh9hLg1oz2-ErTOq) - all fields seems right except of Address which is null

Comment: Update: When I add "Addres" (whole class) to the binding list it binds the appropriate address class, like [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yI9sfHmtp4flYu-1_UxZc_b0w3HHA6Br). But it still causes sql error about duplication of UserProfileForeignKey in the Address class .

Comment: After calling update method check the state of address entity: db.Entry<Address>(userProfile.Address).State;

This should be set to Modified. If that is correct verify in the db that userProfile is actually associated with that specific AddressId

Comment: userProfile is associated with correct AddressId. The State you asked is "Added", when I changed it like `_context.Entry<Address>(userProfile.Address).State = EntityState.Modified;` a new sql error appeared: _DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions._ ..........It seems some coupling between the 2 classes is still missing, but what?

Comment: Updated my answer :)